# How to disabled minutes and text (Eastern Standard time) from angular datepicker?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

main.html

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <datetimepicker data-ng-model="dateRangeStart" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed' }" data-on-set-time="startDateOnSetTime()" data-before-render="startDateBeforeRender($dates)"></datetimepicker>
</ul>
```

I am using angular directive https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker , if you select date and time with this module it will display `Thu Mar 23 2017 15:46:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` so here is it possible to get rid of `46:38 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` this part i just want hours selection ? 
Ctrl.js

```
$scope.dateRangeStart = new Date();
    $scope.dateRangeStart.setDate($scope.dateRangeStart.getDate() - 1);
    $scope.dateRangeEnd = new Date();
    $scope.endDateBeforeRender = endDateBeforeRender
    $scope.endDateOnSetTime = endDateOnSetTime
    $scope.startDateBeforeRender = startDateBeforeRender
    $scope.startDateOnSetTime = startDateOnSetTime

    function startDateOnSetTime () {
      $scope.$broadcast('start-date-changed');
    }

    function endDateOnSetTime () {
      $scope.$broadcast('end-date-changed');
    }

    function startDateBeforeRender ($dates) {
      if ($scope.dateRangeEnd) {
        var activeDate = moment($scope.dateRangeEnd);

        $dates.filter(function (date) {
            $scope.searchObj.endDate = activeDate._i;
            // console.log(activeDate);
          return date.localDateValue() >= activeDate.valueOf()
        }).forEach(function (date) {
          date.selectable = false;
          // console.log(date);
        })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the minView option in the configuration per the docs.  It's the lowest denomination of time the date picker should show.  Set that to hours or days, however you want it.

Example from above:

```
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed', minView: 'hour' }"
```

Comment: can you give me an example how i set that configuration ?

Comment: added example for you

Comment: thank you that helped , is there any attribute that we can use to get rid of `GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` or make abbrevation (EST)

Comment: I'm commuting now but if no one else has answered that later take a look.  It should be in the docs though.

Answer (score 0):

Joshua Wilborn is correct, set the configuration:

```
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdownStart', renderOn: 'end-date-changed', minView: 'hour' }"
```

Then you can use the [angular-date-time-input](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-date-time-input) directive to format the display of a date in an input box or allow users to enter a valid date with the keyboard.